# Cannot Set HTTP Headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am running Rails 5.2.2 in development mode (have the same problem in production too) and I'm trying to prevent some pages from caching. In my `application_controller.rb` file I have the following code

```
def 
  response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
  response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
  response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
end
```

This code above produces the following Cache-Control header in Chrome & Firefox.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
```

What am I doing wrong that prevents the Cache-Control header from being set to the value I provided in my code?

Comment: Have you added this method in `before_action`?

Comment: Yes, and I'm 100% positive it's executing because the pragma header is set only when I call the function with before_action.

Comment: @CannonMoyer you must try this `response.set_header("Header-Name", "Header value")`